# installing a specific version of Python into a specific folder. ./configure command only installing into current directory OSX

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I have searched the internet and cobbled together instructions for installing Python however I am running into an issue with the `./configure` command which a few months ago I thought was working correctly (I could be wrong).

My use case is that I want to install Python3.8.6 into a specific folder called "PythonProjects" on my Desktop and then modify OSX to use that Python 3.8.6 version.

The command syntax I found that I believe I should be using is:

```
 ./configure --prefix=/directory/path/to/where/you/want/python/installed
```

So what I've done is a "cd" into the directory where I have the Python3.8.6 binaries that I downloaded and `tar -zxfv` (uncompressed). let's say that location is `cd ~/Downloads/Python3.8.6`

And now I want to install Python3.8.6 into a folder on my Desktop called "PythonProjects"

```
./configure --prefix=/Users/myusername/Desktop/PythonProjects
```

However, when I execute the ./configure command, it simply installs Python3.8.6 into the current `~/Downloads/Python3.8.6` folder where the downloaded binaries are, not into the `Desktop/PythonProjects` target folder.

I could be doing this all wrong and misunderstanding what the ./configure command is all about. Am looking for help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you've got your wires crossed somewhere. Configure is normally used when building Python from C source code — and then only as the first step of the process — not when installing a binary. Exactly what did you download?

Comment: I downloaded "Python-3.8.6.tgz"

Comment: Among the unpacked files, you should find a file named [README.rst](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/README.rst) which has a section called "[Build Instructions](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/README.rst#build-instructions)". Did you read and understand those instructions?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that in continuing with the process, `make` will "prepare" the directory build I passed to it in the ./configure --prefix step. And then `make install` actually builds that directory. Meaning, once I executed `make install` in Terminal, voila the directory I passed to the `./configure --prefix=/Users/myusername/Desktop/PythonProjects` was created on the Desktop (i.e., the "Python Projects" folder showed up)